# Prevent UITableView header from being replaced by next header?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewanimation, uitableviewsectionheader

What is the best way to prevent what you see in the first picture from happening, so that it does look like in the second picture, where `Header 2` stays right beneath `Header 1`.

The reason I wanna do that is because of a "UI-Glitch" when animating the height of the tableView. (Described in more detail below :)

[image: Header Clipped]

[image: Header not Clipped]

In my other project I pinned the top of the tableView to another view (`topView`). When the user scrolls down, I set  `topView.heightConstraint.constant` to a smaller value and animate the change in layout with `UIView.animate - rootView.layoutIfNeeded()`.

The problem I'm facing is when the User scrolls down so fast / much, that `Header 2` replaces `Header 1` for a moment. It then looks like `Header 1` is glitching beneath the topView a little bit and then reappearing again. (This doesn't take much scrolling velocity when there are only a few rows in Section 1)

So I want to prevent this from happening by keeping `Header 2` beneath `Header 1` as long as the animation has finished.

I tried to change the frame of the header with

```
tableView.headerView(forSection: 0)?.frame = /* New frame */
```

but couldn't get it to work... :(

Comment: As described in the end it causes a "UI-Glitch" which a don't like. I could live with the bug but it disturbs me every time it occurs.
I will reference it at the top :)